# Pandas - change cell values so that they equal the deviation from the average across the row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say that I have a df that looks like the following:

[image: Sample Df]

The average of rows x, y, and z are 1, 2, and 10, respectively.

I want to turn the df into the following:

[image: desired result]

so that the cell values reflect the deviation from the row's average.

The dataframes I'm working with are a bit bigger, ~1500 rows by ~50 cols. Is there an elegant way to achieve this? I can do it the brute math way by creating a matrix with all the averages then finding the difference between the df value and the new matrix value, but I'm wondering if there's a smarter or easier way to do this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `out = df.sub(df.mean(axis=1),axis=0)` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you calculate the `mean` computed row-wise and then calculate the difference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3],'y':[2,3,4]})

mean = df.mean(axis=1)
df = df.sub(mean,axis=0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     x    y
0 -0.5  0.5
1 -0.5  0.5
2 -0.5  0.5
```